# Any facebook api to get city / place id based on longitude and latitude

Tags: facebook, geolocation, location

I am able to get current latitude and longitude using html5. I have tried with

https://graph.facebook.com/search?type=place&value=1&center=12.9715987,77.59456269999998&distance=1000&limit=100&offset=0

through facebook console. It gives me list of places with place id. But what I want is City's place id.

Comment: Use some other API, like Google Maps API.

Comment: but to add checkin in facebook we need place_id which we can get from facebook only

Comment: What, you want the user to check in “into” a _city_?

Comment: nop , i want give option to a user to check into city , as facebook does. As user may not be in a place , which is given by above request.